# Why does this boolean expression not return true?

Tags: javascript

I am implementing a tic-tac-toe game in JavaScript. Why does the following boolean statement not run inside the `if` block (not return true)?

```
if("O" == "O" == "O") {
    console.log("player 'O' has won the game.");
}
```

Is this because `"O" = "O"` is evaluated to return `true`. Then `true` is compared to `"O"` which returns `false`?

If so how can I compare if characters at index 0, 3, 6 in `["O", "O", "X", "O", "X", "O", "O"]` are equal to one another?

Update code.

```
game.prototype.winCondition = function () {
    var winningConditions = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,8], [1,4,7], [2,5,8], [3,6,9], [1,5,9], [3,5,7]];
    winningConditions.some(function(element, index, array) {
        var player = this.spaceArray[element[0] - 1];
        if((this.spaceArray[element[0] - 1] == this.spaceArray[element[1] - 1]) && (this.spaceArray[element[1] - 1] == this.spaceArray[element[2] - 1])) {
            //some body won
            console.log("you win!!!");
            //alert(player + " has won at " + element);
            return true;
        }
    }.bind(this));
};
```

Comment: In Javascript, you use the `&&` operator to evaluate multiple conditions:  `if (a == b && c == d)`.

Comment: Yes - you're not even extracting items from an array, you're just comparing strings to one another. Is there more code?

Comment: (Side note) You have a typo: `[7,8,8]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should write two separate equality `==` checks for this :

```
if (smth[0] == smth[3] && smth[3] == smth[6] )
```

Answer (score 0):

One trick to keep the code shorter while still (arguably) easier to read is to check the concatenation of the three. I.e. `if (x[0]+x[3]+x[6] === "OOO") ...`.

You can also check for both sides with:

```
if ("OOO/XXX".indexOf(x[0]+x[3]+x[6]) >= 0)
```

Comment: I would not use this strategy because it will be difficult for someone else who is reading the code.

Comment: @camrydash: That's why I added "arguably". Of course as usual the ability to read depends on the text but also on the reader. I think however that the first version (checking only for "OOO") is not difficult to read at all even for novices.

Answer (score 0):

> Is this because "O" = "O" is evaluated to return true. Then true is compared to "O" which returns false?

Yes.

In this case with just three items, it's easiest to just use `a === b && b === c`, but you could make a helper function to check the equality of an indefinite number of items:

```js
function allEqual() {
  var argArray = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);

  return argArray.every(function(el) {
    return el === argArray[0];
  });
}

console.log(allEqual());
console.log(allEqual("O", "O", "O", "O"));
console.log(allEqual("X", "O", "O", "O"));
console.log(allEqual("O", "X", "O", "O"));
console.log(allEqual("O", "O", "O", "X"));
```